# error while deploying angular 8 app to heroku

Tags: javascript, angular, heroku, npm

i have an angular app whice i would like to deploy to heroku server,
when triyng to push it to heroku its throws this error while building the app.

```
>  remote: ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/styles.scss)
remote: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
remote: Error: Failed to find 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
remote:   in [
remote:     /tmp/build_d62dc57294d62a0a94ce724ef0a3a389/src
remote:   ]
remote:     at resolveModule.catch.catch (/tmp/build_d62dc57294d62a0a94ce724ef0a3a389/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13)
remote:  @ ./src/styles.scss 1:14-241
remote:  @ multi ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css ./src/styles.scss
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! weather-task@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the weather-task@0.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.RIXvs/_logs/2019-12-02T12_55_26_250Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

this is my server which should server the page:

```
   const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');

    const app = express();

    // Serve only the static files form the dist directory
    app.use(express.static('./dist'));

    app.get('/*', function (req, res) {

      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
    });
    console.log(__dirname + '/dist/index.html')
    // Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

and my package.json with all the dependencies

```
{
  "name": "weather-task",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "11.0.0",
    "npm": "6.11.3"
  }
}
```

im trying to figure what is missing in my package json and how to resolve it.
any suggestions please?
thanks!

Comment: Something's up with Bootstrap (The CSS-Framework) `Error: Failed to find 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`